# I am making a SQL database of categories and subcategories. What is the best way to link these tables?

Tags: sql, database, performance

The database has a table called **"categories"** with columns *CATEGORY_ID*(primary key) and *CATEGORY_NAME.*

I have subcategories for each category.
For better accessing which is the best method from the below methods.

***Method 1:*** The *"CATEGORY_ID"* column in the **"categories"** table is a ***FOREIGN KEY*** in the **"subcategories "** table.

***Method 2:*** Maintaining a separate table for each category representing the subcategories.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Sure, to clarify, I have added a picture of the categories table. When I do the subcategories table, should all of the subcategories for every category be in one table or should there be a separate table for the subcategories of each category?

Comment: I would use the `"CATEGORY_ID"` column in the "categories" table is a FOREIGN KEY in the `"subcategories "` table. because you can `join` one table to get multiple CATEGORY items easier.

Comment: Ok, I will try that out. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use same table for category and sub category

like 
Table Categories
[CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, PARENT_CATEGORY_ID]

In case you don't know how many sub categories are there.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is just an example, the scenario is as follows: We have a product table where all the records of products are stored. Same way we will have customer table where records of customers are stored. The daily sales keep the record of all the sales. This sales table will keep record of which product who has purchased. So linking is to be done from Sales table to product table and customer table.
The query to  link the two tables is as follows:SELECT product_name, customer.name, date_of_sale  FROM sales, product, customer WHERE  product.product_id = sales.product_id and customer.customer_id >= sales.customer_id LIMIT 0, 30

Answer (score 0):

It is better to go with **Method 1** since it is more scalable.

Let me elaborate on this. ***If we go with method 1, we need to maintain 2 tables only that is Categories and Subcategories***. In future if we have new categories or subcategories we can directly deal with this 2 tables.

If we consider same situation with **Method2** then we need to create new tables every time, this may become maintenance overhead.

Comment: This makes quite a bit of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me be a bit more direct.  You explain in a comment that Method 2 is a separate table for each category.  If so, then Method 2 -- in general -- is just wrong.

There are two methods for storing this type of information.  One is a `Categories` table with a (single) `Subcategories` table.  The `Subcategories` table would have `CategoryId`, a foreign key reference back to `Categories`.  This is the normalized data model.

The second method is to store everything in one table.  Each row would be a category/subcategory combination.  Information about a given category would be duplicated across multiple rows, so this is not a normalized approach.  However, this is a typical approach when doing dimensional modeling for decision support systems.

If the subcategories are just names of things, there is a third approach, which would be to store a list of the subcategories within each `Category` row.  The list would *not* be a delimited string.  It would be JSON, a nested table, XML, array, or similar collection data type supported by the database you are using.  I am mentioning this as a possibility, but not recommending it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I now see why method 2 would be counterproductive.